# Do Nvidia's new GPUs support G-Sync monitors?

Tags: display, nvidia-graphics-card, hardware-rec, g-sync

Nvidia's new Turing GPUs, such as the RTX 2070, RTX 2080, and RTX 2080 TI are different from their Pascal GPUs, such as the GTX series.

On [Nvidia's official website](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/g-sync/supported-gpus), the RTX GPUs are not listed as supporting G-Sync.  However, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_G-Sync), they are listed.  (Wikipedia lists Nvidia's official website as their reference.)

Do Nvidia's Turing GPUs support G-Sync in a monitor?  If so, is it native, or only partially supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On Nvidia's official website, the RTX GPUs are not listed as supporting G-Sync.

Nvidia has not updated their G-Sync page in almost 2 years.  The list of supported GPU is out of date.

> Do Nvidia's Turing GPUs support G-Sync in a monitor?

Yes;  RTX cards support G-Sync

[image]

Source: [Additional Features and Benefits](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/20-series/)

> If so, is it native, or only partially supported?

It's fully supported.